# Fatal error disappeared when running with GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I have a program which produces a fatal error with a testcase, and I can locate the problem by reading the log and the stack trace of the fatal. It turns out that there is a read operation upon a null pointer.

But when I try to attach GDB to it and set a breakpoint around the suspicious code, the null pointer just cannot be observed! The program works smoothly without any error.

This is a single-process, single-thread program, and I didn't experience this kind of thing before. Why is it?

Appended: I also tried to call the pause() system call before the fatal-trigger code, and expected to make the program sleep before the fatal point and then attach GDB on it on-the-fly, sadly, no fatal error occurred.

Comment: Try debugging with `valgrind`/`memcheck`?

Comment: ahh, Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, applied to programming

Comment: The notorious [heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug)

Comment: Likely an uninitalized pointer, or a value that is used as condition for setting the pointer, that happens to be zero in non-debug. When debugging it has a different start value.

Comment: Related: *[Crashes normally, but not with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507336/)* (2011)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only guesswork without looking at the code, but debuggers sometimes do this:

- They initialize certain stuff for you
- The timing of the operations is changed

I don't have a quote on GDB, but I do have one on valgrind (granted the two do **wildly** different things..)

[My program crashes normally, but doesn't under Valgrind, or vice versa. What's happening?](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes)

> When a program runs under Valgrind,
>   its environment is slightly different
>   to when it runs natively. For example,
>   the memory layout is different, and
>   the way that threads are scheduled is
>   different.

Same would go for GDB.

> Most of the time this doesn't make any
>   difference, but it can, particularly
>   if your program is buggy.

So the true problem is likely in your program.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several things happening.. The timing of the application can be changed, so if it's a multi threaded application it is possible that you for example first set the ready flag and then copy the data into the buffer, without debugger attached the other thread might access the buffer before the buffer is filled or some pointer is set.

It's could also be possible that some application has anti-debug functionality. Maybe the piece of code is never touched when running inside a debugger.

One way to analyze it is with a core dump. Which you can create by `ulimit -c unlimited` then start the application and when the core is dumped you could load it into gdb with `gdb ./application ./core` You can find a useful write-up here: http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/linux/gdb-gnu-debugger-intro.php

Comment: Thanks, but as I've said, there should be any thread issue, since it's single-threaded. And, unfortunately, I don't have the permission to run ulimit :\

Comment: Ow, totally missed that... More coffee! Excuse me!

Answer (score 0):

If it is an invalid read on a pointer, then unpredictable behaviour is possible. Since you already know what is causing the fault, you should get rid of it asap. In general, expect the unexpected when dealing with faulty pointer operations.